# create database, simplest way possible using psql commands

Tags: postgresql

So I installed postgreSQL version 9.2.4 using the default installer settings on Windows 7 64 bit.
Then I launched the SQL Shell(psql) command line tool and enter all the defaults plus the password I used during the install.  It logs in.  The problem is that a database cannot be created, or so it appears.

I typed in creatdb mydb

also tried CREATE DATABASE mydb

I assume something happens, but when I type \list I just see the default installed databases.

Am I missing something here?  Coming from MySQL and this simple task is puzzling.
No errors, nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you should give the tutorial a try first: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/tutorial.html

Specifically, this part: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/tutorial-createdb.html

```
$ createdb mydb
```

Alternatively from the psql console:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb; -- note the ; at the end
```

Comment: Read that and tried that.  No errors and \list doesn't show that it got created.

Comment: That's very weird, the `createdb mydb` should either work or give an error, for example: `createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "myuser" does not exist`

Comment: Perhaps to make things a bit easier on Windows, you can try something like pgadmin3: http://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: Is it perhaps I am logging into the shell utility all wrong?  I am logging in pressing "enter" "enter" (defaults) until the pass then it grants me in as the default.  Keep in mind I have done nothing post install.  I just installed and ran the command util.

Comment: Yea I know about the admin gui, but I like command line and it should work.

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem now. The `createdb mydb` command is not a SQL command but a separate program like `psql`. So instead of opening `psql` you execute `createdb mydb`

Comment: This was it.  tried CREATE DATABASE mydb; (don't forget the ;).  That worked.  A big thank you for sorting this.